# JavaScript throws a read property 'submit' error

Tags: javascript

I got this error:

> ?shiftType=4:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined
> at success (?type=4:49)
> success @ ?type=4:49

This is my JavaScript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--      
    function addLatlng()
    { 
        var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };

        function success(pos) 
        {
            

            var crd = pos.coords;
            
            console.log(crd.latitude);
            console.log('Your current position is:');
            console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
            console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
            console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
            document.getElementById('latlng').value = crd.latitude + "-" + crd.longitude;
            document.openShiftForm.submit();
        };

        function error(err) {
            console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
            document.getElementById('latlng').value = "ERROR" + "-" + err.message;
            document.openShiftForm.submit();
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    
    }
    // -->
</script>
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="openShiftForm">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="latlng" name="latlng" value="">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="openShift">';
echo '<button type="button"  onclick="addLatlng()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" name="openShift" value="1">'.$shiftTypeArray[intval($_SESSION['openShiftType'])]['name'].' open shift</button>';
echo '</form>';
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Giving a form a "name" attribute does not make it available as a variable.

Comment: but how to make it available?

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, try to add an id to form and then `submit()` it. Like this:

```
  echo '<form action="" id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="openShiftForm">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" id="latlng" name="latlng" value="">';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="openShift">';
  echo '<button type="button"  onclick="addLatlng()" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" name="openShift" value="1">'.$shiftTypeArray[intval($_SESSION['openShiftType'])]['name'].' open shift</button>';
  echo '</form>'; 
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  

  function addLatlng()
  { 
    
    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) 
    {
      

      var crd = pos.coords;
      
      console.log(crd.latitude);
      console.log('Your current position is:');
      console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
      console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
      console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
      document.getElementById('latlng').value = crd.latitude + "-" + crd.longitude;
      document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    };

    function error(err) {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
      document.getElementById('latlng').value = "ERROR" + "-" + err.message;
      document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    };

    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    
  }
  // -->
  </script>
```

Comment: Ciao Giovanni,

thank you very much for your help!

I change this to this:
HTML part:
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="openShiftForm" id="openShiftForm">
JavaScript part:
document.getElementById('openShiftForm').submit();

Now I got this error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at success

Can you help again?

Comment: Ciao, since I cannot share with you a snippet because Geolocation will be always disabled by Feature Policy, I have done a test: went [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation), copied your code updated and then tested. It works! Just do a check and let me know.

Comment: yes, it works, it shows me my position

This is my whole console log with my app:
Your current position is:
?type=5:45 Latitude : 53.2063064
?type=5:46 Longitude: 8.5153522
?type=5:47 More or less 59 meters.
?type=5:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at success (?type=5:49)

Comment: I don't know, what browser you are using?

Comment: google chrome browser, but as I wrote: the Maps API is working

Comment: Ok but "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at success" problem still there or I'm wrong?

Comment: yes, the error still exists. When i inspect the HTML sourcecode i can see, that the success function added value to HTML object id=latlng: <input type="hidden" id="latlng" name="latlng" value="53.2012886-8.571322">

Comment: CONSOLE LOG:
Your current position is:
(index):45 Latitude : 53.2052886
(index):46 Longitude: 8.571322
(index):47 More or less 30 meters.
(index):49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    at success ((index):49)

Comment: i have no submit button in this form. is it necessary?

Comment: No it isn't necessary.

Comment: I solved it. I had an unclosed <form> tag in my code before..

Comment: Very happy to ear that :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

So in the success function you are calling

```
document.openShiftForm.submit()
```

The `document` does contain the form, but it does not automatically add elements so you can access them with dot notation. So you cannot access them by writing something like `document.[name of your element]`. That's why you are getting the error, `cannot read property submit of undefined`, because `openShiftForm` does not exist in the document at the top level that way.

The way you can access your element is with some of the getter methods that the document object provides. Here you could probably write something like:

```
const form = document.getElementById("openShiftForm");
```

Doing it this way would require you to add a `id` property to your form element in the html of `openShiftForm`. Once you have access to the form element you call pull out the fields that you need, and do what you need to do with them. You could do this in your `onsuccess` function.

This is just one way to do it. If you google around you will find that the `document` object has many methods that you can use to access and manipulate the dom. Getting more familiar with those methods will help you figure out how you want to set this up.

Comment: Hey Pradeep,

thank you very much for your detailed answer. I though i understood it, but it still dont work..

I changed this:
HTML part:
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="openShiftForm" id="openShiftForm">
JavaScript part:
document.getElementById('openShiftForm').submit();

Now I got this error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at success

Thank you very much

Comment: So there isn't just a ```submit``` function that you can just call on the ```form``` element. It's something that you have to explicitly set. So you can do two things. 1. You can set it, or 2. You can just do what you need to do in that block of code, and run the function then . Also, how are you testing? I see for your HTML you are just running echo 'HTML string', are you running this in the terminal? or in a browser?

Comment: in  a browser. 
with $_POST['latlng'] I grap the data on the submit destination site

Comment: But how to submit the form by (or from) the success function?

Comment: i have no submit button in this form. is it necessary?

Comment: Yes. You will need a button or some element that lets the user trigger the submit once they complete the form. Take a look at this example, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onsubmit.  Here they aren't using a button, but they use an input that shows up like a button. When the button is clicked, it fires the onsubmit on the form it self.